# Interpretation of adapted process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

A process $(X_{t})_{t \in T}$ is $(\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t \in T}$-adpated if for every $t$, $X_{t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable.

But since the variable $X_{t}$ is interpreted as the state of process at time $t$ and $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ is interpreted as the information know at time $t$, why we don't require $\mathcal{F}_{s} \subset \sigma(X_{t})$ for $s < t$ ?

Answer (score 1):

When you start learning martingale theory, the filtrations that you see are almost always just the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(X_s : s \leq t)$, and in this case it's clear that $X$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}$.

Indeed, most filtrations are defined as a natural filtration for some process.
However, we might then construct new processes from our original one without wanting to change the underlying filtration.
A classic example would be the maximum process
$$
M_t
= \sup_{s\leq t} X_s,
$$
which is adapted to $\mathcal{F}$, but in which $\mathcal{F}_t$ contains strictly more information that $\sigma(M_s : s \leq t)$.

Also, it is useful to make statements comparing processes like "the maximum of two submartingales is a submartingale."
In order to even make sense of this, the two processes must be submartingales with respect to the same filtration even though they will most likely have different natural filtrations.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\geq 0}$, a process $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is *adapted* if each $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable. On the other hand, for *predictable* process, the random variables are measurable with respect to slightly smaller $\sigma$-algebras. Indeed, given $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\geq 0}$, a process $\{Y_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is *predictable* if each $Y_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable. i.e., at each time step $n$, one can predict the next value $Y_{n+1}$ of the process using only the information available at time $n$, that is, the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_n$.

---

Analogy with *gambling*: An **adapted** process $X_n$ represents the cumulative gain or loss after $n$ turns, while a **predictable** process represents a betting strategy. It stands to reason that your betting strategy at the $n$-th step can depend only on the outcome of the previous $n-1$ steps, but not on the $n$-th step itself.